# Java swing how to draw an image as a quadrilateral by using 4 points

Tags: java, swing, drawing, quadrilaterals

I want to draw an image as a quadrilateral by using the points of the 4 corners as parameters. Does Java have anything already built in for that? I've seen a similar post but the solution given did not seem to do what I want. The function call would look like this:

```
wall.drawTexture(Point topLeft, Point topRight, Point bottomLeft, Point bottomRight);
```

My wall class already contains an attribute "`BufferedImage` texture".

[image]

Context: I'm doing a raycaster engine. I can split my image into smaller columns to correspond to my pixel columns on the 3D view but the texture integrity isn't very high. I thought by only using the first and last ray to hit the same wall face and convert to a parallelogram instead would solve my problem. It would also probably be faster than drawing column by column.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that is compilable and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i dont have any code, im just looking for a function that could make what you see in the drawing and what i explained.

Comment: *"I've seen a similar post.."* Link?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Transformations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html). I think you would want the shear transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use drawLine. Something where it draws a line between 1-2, 1-3, 4-2, 4-3 .

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you are suggesting.  Im trying to take an image and draw it as a quadrilateral. Ive added an image to help clarify.

Comment: Once you get your 4 points from the image, use draw line to connect them maybe.

Comment: yes, i think i can use a double shear to get the desired result. Some math would be needed to get the proper scale factors in order for the image to align with my points but i believe it can work. Big tks!  Edit: actually i dont need to shear twice, even better.

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is that you consider the following:

```
paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    // Rendering hints can visually smooth out the graphics with
    // anti aliasing.
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}
```

Other possibilities would be looking at the `AffineTransform` and related classes where you can manipulate various aspects of a graphics context (e.g. shearing, blurring, etc).